# How to post as Facebook page on other pages or profiles

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-profile

I set the setting "Use Facebook as...." to my Facebook page. However, when I'm posting on other walls than on the pages wall, the post is made as my Facebook user. How can I post as Facebook page on other pages/walls/groups?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot post on personal profiles or groups with a Facebook fan page. Only another Facebook fan page.